# Applying img hover to a certain picture only?

Tags: css, image, hover

I would like to add the `img hover` specifically to the top banner and no other image. Is there any code that lets you do this? Thank you for any reply.

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Cascade Studios™</TITLE>
<style>
body
{
background-image:url('http://icpy.webs.com/boxes/background.png');
background-repeat:repeat-y
position:center;
}
img {
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}
</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<center>
<img src="http://icpy.webs.com/boxes/cascade.png"/><br>
<div id="main_box" style="position:absolute; left:120px; top:190px; z-index:1;"> 
<img src="http://icpy.webs.com/boxes/left.png" name="inlineframe" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"/></div> 


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it unique ID and define CSS rule for that ID:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Cascade Studios™</TITLE>
<style>
body
{
background-image:url('http://icpy.webs.com/boxes/background.png');
background-repeat:repeat-y
position:center;
}
img {
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
#top_banner:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}
</style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<center>
<img id="top_banner" src="http://icpy.webs.com/boxes/cascade.png"/><br>
<div id="main_box" style="position:absolute; left:120px; top:190px; z-index:1;"> 
<img src="http://icpy.webs.com/boxes/left.png" name="inlineframe" border="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"/></div> 


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just give that one particular image a class...

```
img {
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 }
.topbanner:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}
```

Then in your HTML

```
<img class="topbanner" src="http://icpy.webs.com/boxes/cascade.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give id to the top banner image and apply :hover pseudo-class on that as shown below:

```
img#top_banner:hover {
//hover styles comes here
}
```